# Encoding of high cardinality multi-label categorical feature?

Tags: dataset, data-cleaning, data-wrangling, categorical-encoding

This is the problem of binary classification:
"1" - the subscriber is a driver (belongs to the segment of drivers),
"0" - the subscriber is not a driver (does not belong to the segment of drivers).

The files **[tabular_data.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15mMTRvQAYR9uMW0zeawhDyrX-guIQGNt/view?usp=sharing)** and **[hashed_feature.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11g8Gw23J3-lPIFGEvRob26lW-9td_8Qq/view?usp=sharing)**  ̶    here are descriptive characteristics for 4084 subscribers ("ID" is the subscriber ID).
The train.csv file is data about the target label (subscriber id and corresponding binary target).

The tabular_data.csv file contains numerical data on the subscriber's activity for 12 periods.
• period - period number (consecutive periods, 1 - the newest);
• id - subscriber ID;
• feature_0 - feature_49 - data on the subscriber's activity in the corresponding period.

The hashed_feature.csv file is a set of hashed values of one categorical variable for the subscriber.
• id - subscriber ID;
• **feature_50** - hash from the value of the categorical variable.

*I faced the following problems:*

1. How should I encode feature_50 for ML algorithm? This feature contains approximately 5k unique values and each user can have almost 1k of these values. As I think one hot encoding is not very helpful here, but what technique should I use in this case?
2. NA filling strategy for feature_0 - feature_49 (*I've only tried pandas filling strategies*)
3. Make use of period variable?
   I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

When you have high cardinality I suggest you two options (one doesn't exclude the other):

- Aggregate least frequent categories into one called other
- Use Neural Network with an embedding layer for high cardinality categories. In case you don't know what an embedding is, it is just a table that map each category into a vector of *k* features (*k* your choice)